# Почему при маленьком разрешении экрана гамбургер вылазит за пределы блока-обертки?

Tags: html, css

При просмотре сайта с уменьшенным окном браузер вылазит гамбургер, но при просмотре в отладчике на маленьком разрешении, он не вылазит. Почему так и кому верить? Может это из-за того, что я не привязал гамбургер к обертке, но я прописывал для wrapper-а свойство position: relative

Сайт https://ct61276.tmweb.ru/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня в маленьком окне не вылезает, и в панели устройств не вылезает, обновите без кэша, в новой вкладке посмотрите

Comment: проверьте на других устройствах, в разных браузерах

Comment: на смартфоне нормально, а на ПК при уменьшении экрана браузера вылазит, причем во всех браузерах

Comment: очень странно, попробуйте на другом пк или в виртуалке

Comment: а вы на ноутбуке смотрели?

Answer (score 0):

`devtools` вам зачем? Вы же сами приколотили его на `60px` от правого края `viewport`.

[image]